# Python Pandas: how to unmelt without pivot()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1":[1,2,3,4],
    "col2":[1,2,3,4],
    "PARMAM_NAME":["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    "PARMAM_VALUE":[100, 200, 300, 400],
})
```

[image]

What I want it to be converted to:

[image]

Is there a **simple** possible way to do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you perse dont want pivot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-stacking) in a one-liner like this.

```
df.set_index(["col1", "col2", "PARMAM_NAME"])["PARMAM_VALUE"].unstack().reset_index()
```

Basically I'm putting the other columns in the index in the beginning (`col1`, `col2`) followed by the column to pivot (`PARMAM_NAME`). Afterwards I unstack this last index over the `PARMAM_VALUE`. To finish, I reset the index to move `col1` and `col2` from the index back to the dataframe.

Although, if you are fine with [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), you can also do it like this:

```
df.pivot_table("PARMAM_VALUE", ["col1", "col2"], "PARMAM_NAME").reset_index()
```

Comment: This is awesome!.  Note: `pivot_table` method would be nice too but it would not check duplicated values because it would aggregate the values

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `append=True` for `MultiIndex` and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), then remove unnecessary columns and join to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('PARMAM_NAME', append=True)['PARMAM_VALUE'].unstack()
df = df.drop(['PARMAM_NAME','PARMAM_VALUE'],axis=1).join(df1)
print (df)
   col1  col2      a      b      c      d
0     1     1  100.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
1     2     2    NaN  200.0    NaN    NaN
2     3     3    NaN    NaN  300.0    NaN
3     4     4    NaN    NaN    NaN  400.0
```